# Automator and Batch Adding Keywords to Images?

Tags: automator

Is there a way to use automator (or something else) to batch add keywords to photos selected in finder?

Answer (score 1):

### [iPhoto](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/)

would do exactly that for you. You can define your own keywords by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and apply them using the "Manage my Keywords" window or the Info-pane <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

[image: iPhoto manage my keywords]