# How do I add keywords to iPhoto images using Automator

Tags: photos.app, automator

I have an Automator service that adds selected photos to iPhoto. I would like it to also add a specific keyword to these photos.

How can I do this?

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35286/automator-and-batch-adding-keywords-to-images) question, but the only answer does not set the keywords via automator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the “Import to iPhoto” Automator action, that returns a list of iPhoto photos you can process. Just add an “Applescript” action after your import action with the following script:

```
tell application "iPhoto"
    repeat with importedPhoto in (input as list)
        select importedPhoto
        assign keyword string "your keyword"
    end repeat
end tell
```

– that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed do the trick. You left out the word `string` after `keyword`, though. I went ahead and edited it in to help future visitors.